# How to use alert message for Validation errors using Html.Validate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How to display alert for errors using Html Validate or Html ValidateFor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#RegisterForm").bind('invalid-form.validate',
    function (event, validator) {
    alert(validator.errorMap.FName);
    console.log(validator.errorMap);
    });
    });
</script>


@using(Html.BeginForm()){
    <span>First Name: </span>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FName)
    @{Html.ValidateFor(model => model.FName);}
}
```

Comment: why you nee this  @{Html.ValidateFor(model => model.FName);}... ? you can simple use  @Html.ValidateFor(model => model.FName); right

Comment: refer this link http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can try extending the validation summary like this:

```
public static class ValidationSummaryAlert
{
    public static string ValidationSummaryWithAlert(this HtmlHelper ext)
    {
        if (!ext.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var alertMessage = (from item in ext.ViewData.ModelState
                                where item.Value.Errors.Any()
                                  && item.Key.Equals("Popup")
                                select new { Message = item.Value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage, item.Key }).SingleOrDefault();

            return
                string.Format(
                    "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">$(function() {{alert('{0}')}});</script>",
                    alertMessage);
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then in the View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
    @Html.Raw(Html.ValidationSummaryWithAlert())

    <!-- YOUR CODE -->
}
```